# Cantor middle nth's set for n in [2,3)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Taking the Cantor middle $n$th's set as constructed by successively removing the middle nth's of the interval $[0,1]$ and the resulting sub-intervals, I've seen many calculations of the length of the cantor middle nth's set by calculating the total length of the removed intervals as an infinite geometric series.  Unless I calculated incorrectly, the length of the cantor middle nth's set should have a closed form of $\frac{(n-3)}{(n-2)}$.  I was curious about certain n-values.

1) For $n=2$, I suspect the formula is not immediately applicable as the "r" value in the geometric series is $1$.  But what is the length of the cantor middle halves set?

2) For n in $(2,3)$, the formula suggests the cantor middle nth's set has negative length.  Why does this happen?  The only possibility that has come to mind so far is that the length of the removed intervals does not (for whatever reason) form an infinite geometric series, but this does not seem likely.

Answer (score 1):

You are indeed calculating the length incorrectly.

Fix some appropriate $n$, and consider the Cantor-middle-${1\over n}$th set. How much length do we remove at each stage?

Well, at the $s$th stage, we have $(n-1)^s\over n^s$ length left. This is a geometric sequence with $r={n-1\over n}$, so the limit of the sequence is . . .

Zero!

Remember, it's not a geometric *series* - we're not adding the areas we have at each stage. So actually, for any fixed ratio the length goes to zero.

The **fat Cantor sets** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set#Other_fat_Cantor_sets) are gotten by removing a *decreasing* fraction at each stage - so e.g. first the middle thirds, then the middle ninths, then the middle $81$sts, . . . (this is just one way of doing it).

Answer (score 0):

Removing middle $n$ths for $n>1$ will always leave a set of measure $0 , $ because after $k$ steps of removal the remaining set has measure $(1-1/n)^k , $  which $\to 0 $ as $ k\to \infty.$